# How to make my pig latin translator translate phrases

Tags: java, string, for-loop, java.util.scanner, language-translation

My Pig Latin translator translates words only. I need to make the translator translate phrases as well as words. I tried a couple of times by trying to add a for() loop but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("WHAT DO YOU WANT IM TRYING TO SLEEP!!!!\n"
        + "JUST ENTER WHAT YOU WANT TRANSLATED!!!!! "); 

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in ); 
String phrase = keyboard.nextLine(); 

String[] word = phrase.split(" "); 

for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++ ) 
{ 
char firstLetter = (word[i].charAt(0)); 
if (firstLetter == 'a' || firstLetter == 'e' || firstLetter == 'i' ||    
firstLetter == 'o' || firstLetter == 'u') 
{ 
String vowel = word[i] +"way"; 
System.out.print(vowel); 
} 
else 

{ 
String start = word[i].substring(0,1); 
String end = word[i].substring(1,phrase.length()); 
System.out.print(end + start + "ay"); 
 } }
System.out.println("\n"
        + "NOW LEAVE!!!!!");
}}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't work"? That tells us essentially nothing.

Comment: How fun! I did a pig latin translator many, many years ago, but not in Java. :)

Answer (score 0):

Stick your word translator code in a function which takes in a string and returns a string. Then, for a very simple for loop do:

```
String result = "";
for (String word : phrase.split(" "))
{
    result += translate(word) + " ";
}
```

Something along the lines of that'll help you. You'll get an extra space at the end, and it only handles words separated by spaces, so like I said, it's very basic. But it should get you started.

Comment: To avoid the extra space, you can use a regular for loop, and use an `if` statement (ternary or otherwise) to only add the space if it's not the last word in the phrase.

Comment: I figured it'd be better to let them figure out that minor detail for themselves =P.